# How to read a given "n" input without using an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I have to read a given number of lines and is important not to use an array, also after reading a line I need to save each input in variabales (max. 15 inputs). It was easy with arrays but I'm not allowed to use in my code! Thanks

Comment: *stack the imput in a float (max. 15 inputs).* I don't understand that part

Comment: What exactly are you doing with each line?  It would help if you could provide more details regarding the intended usage.

Comment: Show us how you did it with arrays, maybe that will help add some context to what you're trying to do

Comment: Instead of `char a[32];` just do `char *a = malloc(32);`. There you go, worked around that completely senseless restriction.

Comment: Apparently, each line contains a float. What are you going to do with these floats? For example, you could pick a random float from the file or calculate the average or determine the min and max valuies by looking at them one by one and without storing them in an array.

Comment: I need to read from my keyboard a N number of floats ( n is between 1 and 15) and then I have to use each number inside my code but i'm not allowed to save them in an array

Comment: How do you have to use them? If it's something like calculating total or average then you don't need to store each number separately. You can track the total as you go and calculate the average from the total at the end. If it's something else then you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read them into a list. Here's a rough snippet of such an approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct TNumber
{
    int num;
    struct TNumber * nxt;
}
Number;

int main()
{
    const int MAX = 15;
    Number * numbers = 0;
   //populate numbers list
    Number * nptr = 0;
    int input, n =0 ;
    while (n < MAX && fscanf(stdin, "%d", &input) > 0)
    {
        Number * new = (Number*)malloc(sizeof(Number));
        new->num = input; 
        new->nxt = 0;
        if (numbers == 0)
            numbers = nptr = new;
        else
        {
            nptr->nxt = new;
            nptr = new;
        }
        n++;
    }
    //Output the numbers to check the list
    nptr = numbers;
    while (nptr)
    {
        printf("%d ", nptr->num);
        nptr = nptr->nxt;
    }
}
```